# How do I make an google calendar feed in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, google-calendar-api

I Want to implement a calendar in my TabBar application, it is supposed to show a google-calendar that updates it self (or already contains the feed at that moment) on a "new tab".
I couldn't find anything that really helped me so I'm asking it now instead and please give a beginners kind of answer to me.

Answer (score -2):

You've got a fair amount of research ahead of you.  You couldn't find anything? Hmm. Search stackoverflow for "google calendar iphone" and check out the first page of hits. After reading up a bit, try coming back with specific questions. It's going to depend a lot on how much control you want over the calendar info.

Comment: Well what I want to do is only put a visual calendar in the app that the user can interact with to check out different happenings, happenings that already have been put in a google calendar.

I don't want the users iCal, nor should the user be able to write a new happening on the app's calendar

thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you can just use a UIWebView and an embeddable calendar. http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/publish/